# PHP Running Background jobs without waiting for response Non Blocking mode Like Trigger type

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, yii2, nonblocking

## Objective

My basic objective is to acheive asynchornous triggers in PHP using Yii2 Web Application

I need to run the php batch jobs but i dont want to wait in the **browser / cron** for doing the job.
For running the job i need to use different file of my application like

```
http://myapp/foojob.php
```

The foojob.php should be asynchronously call many php instances[Each instance carries one job] based on the availble jobs in hand. The time limit of the call (foojob.php) is less than 60sec.i need to trigger new php instances before it exceeds timeout value.

## I Referred & Tried

1. [**curl_multi**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) - i could't find the non blocking mode in it .
2. [**fsock_open**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) - This is possible by sending Connection: Close to the call (But fsock open is not always available on many shared hosting servers or its not working properly) . Can you suggest me any Reliable solution with the fsock transport?
3. [**pcntl_exec**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php) -I haven't tried in real time but realtime stats shows 45% servers disabled the function. I dont know the reason why.
4. **stream transport** - I dont know how it works?

## My Questions :

1. **Non blocking async requests** Is there any possible solution that already exists in git to acheive in PHP?
2. Refer me if any other transports i need to look into
3. is there any smart switching transport mechanism (curl/ fsock) based on the environment ?

## Edit:

The application is self-hosted product . it would get work on Various hosting services . Shared Hosting won't allow / Provide any external extensions for their customer .

Comment: Did you take a look at [php-rescue](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) ?

Comment: @old_mountain thanks . i have taken a look. It needs redis Redis 2.2+. Without any hard dependencies would be better for our case ?

Comment: Did you check `ignore_user_abort()`? with that you could use `nohup` if you have unix boxes to make it work.

Comment: try rabbitMQ - it's job scheduler (queue). You create job, and then it's created scheduler start first job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrote one php library for non blocking background jobs. This Library would helps to achieve the objective i posted

Composer Library
https://packagist.org/packages/devbabuind/non-blocking-php

Answer (score 1):

You could take an approach where you send the correct headers to have the browser close the connection and then run the process synchronously and it would appear to be async to the end user.

Here is something I wrote a long time ago that you can see as an example.
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8388-PHP-Defer-execution-of-actions-until-the-script-ends.html

I assume there is some place in yii that you could hook into after the content is sent where you could do a similar thing.

Short version of it 
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    header("Connection: Close");

```
ob_flush(); // headers
echo $html;
flush();

doWork();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . There are some non blocking php concepts are there in socket and commands . This is useful one and i write my own answer with some non blocking php methods here .